# CLR function Unsupported type

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

The building of the following CLR function will get the following error `/* Error: Unsupported type. */` in the automatically generated SQL. Which type caused the problem?  The MSDN document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx was used as an example to create the Clr function.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--     This code was generated by a tool.
--
--     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
--     the code is regenerated.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InitMethod] (@path [nvarchar](MAX), @pattern [nvarchar](MAX), @recursive [bit])
RETURNS /* Error: Unsupported type. */
AS EXTERNAL NAME [ListFiles].[FileList].[InitMethod];
```

The following is the C# code.

```
public class FileInf
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastWriteTime { get; set; }
    public long Length { get; set; }
    public bool IsFile { get; set; }
};

[SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRow")]
public static IEnumerable InitMethod(string path, string pattern, bool recursive)
{
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var files = dir.GetFiles(pattern, recursive ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (var f in files)
    {
        yield return new FileInf
        {
            Name = f.Name,
            LastWriteTime = f.LastWriteTime,
            Length = f.Length,
            IsFile = (f.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory ? false : true
        };
    }
}

public static void FillRow(Object obj, 
  out SqlChars name, 
  out SqlDateTime lastWriteTime, 
  out SqlInt64 Length, 
  out SqlBoolean isFile)
{
    var fileInfo = (FileInf)obj;
    name = new SqlChars(fileInfo.Name);
    lastWriteTime = new SqlDateTime(fileInfo.LastWriteTime);
    Length = new SqlInt64(fileInfo.Length);
    isFile = new SqlBoolean(fileInfo.IsFile);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error you get? number, severity, state, message.

Comment: The error is embedded in the generated code in visual studio (the first block of the code in the question). And then it has error under `AS` because there is no body.

Comment: It looks like the C# is giving back 4 outputs while the function is only set up for 3. Is that right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS 2012 SSDT build CLR with IEnumerable failing on generated syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001853/vs-2012-ssdt-build-clr-with-ienumerable-failing-on-generated-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Change your attribute to `[SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRow",
TableDefinition = "[name] VARCHAR(MAX),[lastWriteTime] DATETIME2(7),[Length] BIGINT, [isFile] BIT")]`.

See [VS 2012 SSDT build CLR with IEnumerable failing on generated syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001853/vs-2012-ssdt-build-clr-with-ienumerable-failing-on-generated-syntax)